# Generate short and Unique String values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building an application, which needs a unique identifier as a UserID (example `A3D7sRt`).

In my case i have instructed not to use numbers only UserID and It should be auto-generated. And also the user id should be 6-8 character long. This is because it has to be easily memorized.

Here using GUID is not an option for me. Because GUID is HEX in nature, so i will be getting less number of unique values compared to a string in the same length.

So what is the efficient way to do that in SQL? Also i do not want to run into frequent unique constraint failed exception.

This value is then used to login to the android mobile client. And no passwords in the login process.

Comment: Easy to remember random strings. Something is wrong here. Why do you need that?

Comment: it is a user id, it should be short in length. users has to memorize it.

Comment: let the users choose their own name and use an ID internally

Comment: that is a good idea too. But this has to be done at the user creation time.

Comment: Why would you want user id to be a random string anyway? Use an int identity, and a unique varchar(8) that the user choose. I really don't see a point of auto - generating user ids, nor do I see a point of using random strings as your primary key. (at least don't use it as a clustered index, it's going to be fragmented and lead to poor performance).

Comment: Or an email address is a pretty standard login these days.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for the info on Performance.

Comment: @JacobH This is for a closed release application. And the requirement is to have such identifier.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is relevant to using an email address as a login, but good luck with your hunt.

Comment: @JacobH This value is used to login to the mobile app. And no passwords here.

Comment: Generate a big integer between 0 and 36^8 then base 36 encode it. (or replace 36 with 62 if case sensitive)

Comment: @MartinSmith so for 0 the user id would be 000000?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes. The actual number could be generated with `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` and base conversions are covered in http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/performing-base-conversions. The probability of a collision is covered here http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Comment: Actually this is the article http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/performing-base-reconversions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) and [Zohar Peled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094533/zohar-peled) comments, I have found a solution.

1. Take a bigint (probably your primary key)
2. Encode it as BASE36
3. bigint must not be 0. Take higher number (or start from) to get
   output length greater than 6 characters

**Here is the T-SQL**

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Val BIGINT = 101722230 

IF (@Val <= 1000000)
BEGIN
    Select 'Very Small ID Try With Large BIGINT' 
    return;
END

WHILE (@Val > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @Result = CHAR(@Val % 36 + CASE WHEN @Val % 36 < 10 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END) + @Result,
            @Val = FLOOR(@Val/36)
END

SElect @Result
```

**Output**

**`1OK9DI`** is the output for the above code. (Verified)

Thank you everyone who helped me by commenting to this question.

Comment: Why do you apparently feel that `00000000` is worse than `11111111` or `aaaaaaaa`?

Comment: When doing the base 36 conversion 0 gives the output 0. As for 11111111 the base 36 conversion is 6M5DZ

Comment: I'm talking about the output of the base 36 conversion. Assuming that you will pad with leading zeroes. This will give you an equal probability of any of the available characters in any available position as long as your random number has an equal probability between 0 and 36 power 8.